# List all agents within an application environment

Tags: udeploy

How do I list all the agents which are used in a specific environment of a Udeploy application?

The resources within the application environment may have hierarchical relationship with an agent at the leaf level of the resource structure.

I need to list the agents only.

Please note that the `getEnvironmentBaseResource` gives me only the name of the top most resource layer, but it does not list the entire resource hierarchy till the agents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a nested call.

First get all environments within the application, with:

[getEnvironmentsInApplication](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.2.1/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/udclient_getenvironmentsinapplication.html)

And then, get all base resources for an environment with [getEnvironmentBaseResources](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.2.1/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/udclient_getenvironmentbaseresources.html)

After that you may parse the response with groovy to get and manipulate the json